# raster calculator (spatial analyst) tool not working in arcpy

Tags: arcpy, spatial-analyst, raster-calculator

I am using arcpy and while running the script it is unable to find RasterCalculator() method? Even after imporiting arpy module

```
>>> RasterCalculator("IDSI_2002.img + IDSI_2007.img","D:/PythonScripts/test.img")
Runtime error 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'RasterCalculator' is not defined
```

Calculator' is not defined

Answer (score 2):

In the Help for [Raster Calculator](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/desktop/latest/tools/spatial-analyst-toolbox/raster-calculator.htm) it says:

> **Note:**
>
> The Raster Calculator tool is intended for use in the application only
>   as a GP tool dialog box or in ModelBuilder. It is not intended for use
>   in scripting and is not available in the ArcPy Spatial Analyst module.

Comment: but it is available it says that but arcpy.gp.RasterCalculator_sa is described right underneath

Comment: @gomapping "the ArcPy Spatial Analyst module" is `arcpy.sa` not `arcpy.gp`.

Comment: well if I create it in model builder and export as python the syntax is arcpy.gp.RasterCalculator_sa, however in my project i gave up on this and used raster math http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/3d-analyst-toolbox/an-overview-of-the-raster-math-toolset.htm